# How to vary response body type based on different failures in OpenAPI?

Tags: openapi

Given an openapi documented endpoint that returns a standard data type:

```
responses:
  '200':
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/DataType'
```

**How can varying failure causes be documented in OpenApi spec?**

For example, there may be an error due to a bad client foo parameter, in which case I want to return a `400` with body

```
{"bad_foo_parameter" : "the underlying foo problem"}
```

While there could be a different bad `bar` response:

```
{"bad_bar_parameter": "the underlying bar problem"}
```

How can I use openapi to document the two different response object types?

There is a [similar question that asks about varying based on parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59234495/how-to-vary-requestbody-type-based-on-a-path-parameter-in-openapi-3-0), I am asking for variance based on error type.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As of version 3.0 there is a `oneOf` descriptor](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/) for multiple types:

```
responses:
  '400':
    description: Bad Request
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          oneOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BadFooError'
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BadBarError'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why [RFC9457](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9457.html) exists. The problem+json model is a generic error schema to relay this type of information back to the client. Your code should implement this generic schema for all of your errors so it returns a consistent response.

In OAS, you can document multiple `examples` of this response.

```yaml
responses:
  "400":
    content:
      "application/problem+json":
        schema:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/problem+json" // define the schema in the components section per the RFC. 
        examples:
          bad_param_1:
            value: {...}
          bad_param_2:
            value: {...}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; I learned something new from it!  Although I think your answer is solving the underlying problem better, my answer still addresses the question directly.

Comment: My answer does directly answer the op question because they are asking about documentation not code generation or validation.  Strictly speaking documentation, examples would be the right answer.  Glad you learned something new though!